# Git - How to maintain executable bit between Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, git, file-permissions

I've been reading a number of threads pointing to `git config core.fileMode false` however I haven't been able to figure out whether or not this is the actual solution to my problem.

The definition of core.filemode is a bit vague

```
core.fileMode
   If false, the executable bit differences between the index and the
   working copy are ignored; useful on broken filesystems like FAT.
   See git-update-index(1). True by default.
```

What I want to solve is this issue. When I create a file and make it executable on Ubuntu, I can push it to the repo and the x permission is maintained. When I pull that file to Windows and make a modification to it, commmit and push, the repo copy loses the execute permission.

Will `core.filemode=False` solve my problem? Or is it simply used to tell git there is no difference between identical files with different permissions?

Is it necessary to `git update-index --chmod=+x <file>` every time I modify a script on Windows?

Comment: To answer this, I'd just try it.

Comment: Do you have FAT or NTFS underneath your git workspace on Windows?